# 2 parallel table with image using itext5

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

how to generate pdf for below content using itext5.

[image]

I am able to get simple table using itext. but for above image how to achieve this?

Below is my code. it is not showing image in the table.

```
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph();
        PdfPCell  cell      = null;
        // Main table
        PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        //mainTable.setWidthPercentage(100.0f);

        // First table
        PdfPCell firstTableCell = new PdfPCell();
        firstTableCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        PdfPTable firstTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        mainTable.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);

        Image img = Image.getInstance(appIconNameWithPath);
        //img.setWidthPercentage(10);

        cell = new PdfPCell(img, true);
        cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        firstTable.addCell(cell);

        mainTable.addCell(firstTableCell);

        // Second table
        PdfPCell secondTableCell = new PdfPCell();
        secondTableCell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        PdfPTable secondTable = new PdfPTable(2);
        secondTable.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        secondTableCell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(appName));
        cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        secondTable.addCell(cell);
        cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(packageName));
        cell.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_RIGHT);
        cell.setBorder(PdfPCell.NO_BORDER);
        secondTable.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: It always helps to share your existing code with problem area to let others help you

Comment: added my code. it does not show image in the table. same format is not coming as  attached image.

Comment: Whats your current output?